# Problem when attempting a saveAndFlush commit (JPA ) when primary key is auto-generated from postGres trigger

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, triggers

I am using spring JPA to attempt to write records to a postGres DB. At the time of the commit, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "col_id" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null)
```

I have the following repository interface:

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository <MyModel, String> {

}
```

, the following model class:

```
@Entity
@Validated
@Table(name = "my_table", schema="common")
public class MyModel {

@Id
@Column(name = "col_id")
private String id;
@Column(name = "second_col")
private String secCol;
@Column(name = "third_col")
private String thirdCol;
@Column(name = "fourth_col")
private String fourthCol;
@Column(name = "fifth_col")
private String fifthCol;


public MyModel() {

}

public MyModel(String id, String secCol, String thirdCol, String fourthCol, String fifthCol) {
    this.id = id;
    this.secCol = secCol;
    this.thirdCol = thirdCol;
    this.fourthCol = fourthCol;
    this.fifthCol = fifthCol;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSecCol() {
    return secCol;
}

public void setSecCol(String secCol) {
    this.secCol = secCol;
}

public String getThirdCol() {
    return thirdCol;
}

public void setThirdCol(String thirdCol) {
    this.thirdCol = thirdCol;
}

public String getFourthCol() {
    return fourthCol;
}

public void setFourthCol(String fourthCol) {
    this.fourthCol = fourthCol;
}

public String getFifthCol() {
    return fifthCol;
}

public void setFifthCol(String fifthCol) {
    this.fifthCol = fifthCol;
}
}
```

, and the relevant part of the service class:

```
public MyModel myModel  (MyModel myModel) {

    MyModel mm = null;
    try {
        mm = myRepo.saveAndFlush(myModel);
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mm;
}
```

UPDATE:
I finally realized that my problem is due to a database trigger that auto-generates primary key against a complex business rule. Also, I assume I might need to use a custom save method rather than the default repo.saveAndFlush? I would be grateful for any ideas given new information. Thanks!

Comment: You have an `@Id` but no generator, so you need to include the id from either the client or generate it yourself. The error isn't wrong so your debugging must be wrong and the fact that you obfuscated your code probably leads to the bug not present in the modified code but rather in the original code.

Comment: @M.Deinum , you are correct, unfortunately I did have to obfiscate the code, which is making solving it an issue. I will try to clarify this morning. However, the id would never be generated (why I have no generator). The user creates the id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem was partly related to not knowing there was a trigger against the primary key that auto-generated to primary key. I guess I need to figure out how to have the java code respect the trigger. –

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced the exact same code in a test project with Postgres and it worked well for me. You are absolutely correct that the values of the model class are not populated. You must share your controller also. It may really help me to help you if I can get a look where your service is being called from. Only that will help me to deduce why your model values are being passed as null in the service call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem was partly related to not knowing there was a trigger against the primary key that auto-generated to primary key. I guess I need to figure out how to have the java code respect the trigger.